# In tealium, is it possible to fire a tag based on a url?

Tags: tealium

At work we are getting ready to convert from Google Tag Manager to Tealium.  In GTM, I know I'm able to fire tags based on a url.

Example: If I have a url such as www.mycompany.com/product1, I know I can make a tag that will parse the url and fire on product1.

Is something like this possible with Tealium?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such functionality is possible in Tealium through the use of a Load Rule. There are various built-in variables in the Data Layer that you can use for this such as "url", "pathname", and "domain". You would simply create a load rule to specify these data layer values on the left, type the values to match on in the right and specify how to evaluate the comparison (e.g. contains, equals, does not equal, etc.).

This load rule would be mapped to a tag you've created and if you had custom logic you wished to add, best practices would be to create an extension that's scoped to that tag and add your logic there.